# Moving Laravel 5.3 project from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: php, windows, composer-php, ubuntu-16.04, laravel-5.3

I recently moved my Laravel 5.3.1 (Repository pattern) project from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 16.04LTs. When I update the composer, I'm getting the following errors.

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
>       PHP Warning:  Uncaught ErrorException: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk): failed to open stream:
>   Success in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:55
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(55):
>   Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'require(/opt/la...',
>   '/opt/lampp/htdo...', 55, Array)
>       #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(55):
>   require()
>       #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(45):
>   composerRequirecf118caaa79186b36c4e6ab213835334('efaf82f485f314c...',
>   '/opt/lampp/htdo...')
>       #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInitcf118caaa79186b36c4e6ab213835334::getLoader()
>       #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ComposerScripts.php(30):
>   require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
>       #5 /usr/share/php/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(238):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Comp in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on
>   line 55
>
> ```
> Warning: Uncaught ErrorException: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk): failed to open stream:
> ```
>
> Success in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:55
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(55):
>   Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'require(/opt/la...',
>   '/opt/lampp/htdo...', 55, Array)
>       #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(55):
>   require()
>       #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(45):
>   composerRequirecf118caaa79186b36c4e6ab213835334('efaf82f485f314c...',
>   '/opt/lampp/htdo...')
>       #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInitcf118caaa79186b36c4e6ab213835334::getLoader()
>       #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ComposerScripts.php(30):
>   require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
>       #5 /usr/share/php/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(238):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Comp in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on
>   line 55
>       PHP Fatal error:  composerRequirecf118caaa79186b36c4e6ab213835334(): Failed opening
>   required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on
>   line 55
>
> ```
> Fatal error: composerRequirecf118caaa79186b36c4e6ab213835334(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/'
> ```
>
> (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/new-abc.test.lk/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on
>   line 55

What I tried:

- Removing the existing vendor folder
- Removing the composer.lock file

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I update the composer"?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused due to the case sensitive issue. I think windows have neglected but Linux didn't.

What I've done is, I've created a custom helper file and included in the composer.json.

The mistake was the actual filename case sensitive didn't match the included file in the composer.json.